# How to add custom close button for antd modal?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, icons, antd

I want to add custom close button for antd modal. How can I do so?

This is my current close button

[image: 1]

I want to add a custom image in place of it like this one.

This is the icon I want to add

[image: 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use API property called closeIcons on Model div like this:

```
<Modal
    title="Modal 1000px width"
    centered
    visible={visible}
    closeIcon={<LogoutOutlined />} // Choose any icon you need.
  >
    <p>some contents...</p>
    <p>some contents...</p>
    <p>some contents...</p>
  </Modal>
```

Reference: [antd API](https://ant.design/components/modal/?ref=checklist.design#API)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just wonder how can I add image. Lets say I have a close image and I import it. If I try closeIcon={image}, this doesnt load up image. How can I add image? Help is greatly appreciated. @Dilli Chalise

Comment: @AbdullahAbbasi You can use like this: 
`closeIcon={<img style={{ height: '20px', width: '20px' }} src={image_url}  /> }`

Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1):

In antd design cross button looks like following and can be used as following code as "CloseOutlined". import it first, then use it where required:

[image: cross button icon in antd design]

```
import { CloseOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

<div className="header-right">                
   <a onClick={() => close()>{<CloseOutlined />}</a>
</div>
```